# cfn-init fails to download S3 file even though "aws s3 cp" works

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a CloudFormation script that uses an `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` section to download a file from an S3 bucket which fails with Access Denied (403).

I have added an IAM role named `s3access` to the machine using an `AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile`. Downloading the file with `aws s3` works:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-26 ~]$ aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/test-file 
.download: s3://my-bucket/test-file to ./test-file
```

But `cfn-init` fails:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-26 ~]$ sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack test --resource EC2 --region us-east-2
Error occurred during build: Failed to retrieve https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/test-file: HTTP Error 403 :
```

I tried setting the IAM role explicitly but that fails too:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-26 ~]$ sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack test --resource EC2 --region us-east-2 --role=s3access
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::196375698259:assumed-role/s3access/i-044499612c92b50f5 is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResource on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:196375698259:stack/test/*
```

I'm thinking of using `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/test-file ./` directly from the user-data but I'd like to know why the `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` fails to assume the role assigned to the EC2 instance.

I found only one similar question - [How can I access protected S3 files in a CFN script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792453/how-can-i-access-protected-s3-files-in-a-cfn-script), but the solution there is to apply an IAM role, which I have already done and `cfn-init` still fails.

Comment: It'd be easier if you show us your template

Comment: I find little advantage to using cfn-init. You could easily just put your aws s3 copy logic in userData of CloudFormation and give your EC2 instance the role/policy rights associated with s3 read access and this will work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to add `AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication` to the `Metadata` of the `EC2Instance`. Details are in:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-authentication.html#cfn-cloudformation-authentication-rolename

For example:

```
EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'    
        Metadata:  
            AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:  
                 rolebased:  
                     type: S3  
                     roleName: !Ref EC2InstanceIAMRole  
                     buckets:  
                         - !Ref TemplateBucket  
            ...
```

The Role has access to the relevant `TemplateBucket`.

The Role is also assigned to the `EC2 instance`.

Some details on the role are here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Before adding this I could download files from s3 via aws cli but the `cfn-init` did not work giving this error:

```
Error occurred during build: Failed to retrieve https://s3.amazonaws.com/FILE: HTTP Error 403 : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>ID</RequestId><HostId>ID</HostId></Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some way to give the cloudformation instance your IAM roles.

- You can put the identify of your **IAM** roles into cloudformation template, for example in your UserData. But, this will make some confidential problem with your **IAM**.
- You can put parameter on stack, so you can specify the **IAM** roles each time you created the stack. This is not really pleasant for testing stack, that need to created a new stack frequently.
- The last one is to launch a new instance and add your **IAM** roles and then make an AMI of that instance. Use this AMI to create the cloudformation stack instance. By using this option, you can make sure that your s3 command is works first on the instance, and you do not have to deal with parameter and confidential problem.